# PHP curl request results in white page when the url contains dots or colons

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

This only happens on my webserver, not on the local system.
I have a curl request like this

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url = 'http://***.***.***.***:8080/api_v1/oauth/token';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

This makes the page loading for a while and just returns a white screen. It is really impossible to show errors, output or just anything else.

Whenever I change the url to another url (existing or not existing) i get proper errors or output if the url makes sense, as long as the url does not contain any dots or colons...

Is there any restriction for the usage or a curlopt I am missing?
I have no control over the target url, I need to consume the api in the ip:port structure.

**UPDATE**

1. The problem is not related to the target URL or data coming in: the same problem occurs when I enter a url that makes no sense at all **as long as it doesn't contain . or :**
2. I guess it is a setting on the webserver since all my tests work fine on localhost (MAMP)
3. Unfortunately I have no access to any logs or files except the ones I upload myself (one.com webhosting)

**UPDATE 2**

Turns out my hoster is blocking all outgoing traffic to implicit IP's and ports other than 80 and 443.
Cancelled my subscription and taking a decent provider now.
Thanks for the help

Comment: What's about the log files? Usually they can be downloaded via FTP.

Comment: "kills my page" -- please include observations, not interpretations! Also make sure you read [ask].

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone My hosting company does not provide access to any other folders than the wwwroot

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have edit the question

Comment: There might be hidden files within the public folder anyway. Did you check this? No log files should be a criterion to change the hoster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my hoster is blocking all outgoing traffic to implicit IP's and ports other than 80 and 443. Cancelled my subscription and taking a decent provider now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

As @Quasimodo suggests, then I'd take a look in the log-file, if I were you. If you're on a Ubuntu-server using Apache, then look at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. A neat trick is to open a terminal and write:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

This will open a running stream to the terminal. Then you can make your curl-request crash (in your browser) and then go back to the terminal and see what new and juicy errors you have received.

It's most likely some configuration-file on your server. So it would be helpful, if you write a couple of specs from that server, such as:
 - Which web server you're using (Apache, Nginx, other)
 - PHP version
... You can find all of these information easily using [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).

My best guess is that you need to [enable PHP_Curl](http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/enabling-curl-in-php-php-ini-wamp-xamp-ubuntu/) for your server configuration, - but it is a buck-wild cowboy shot from the hip.

### Addition 1

I can see that you've just editted the question (that it thinks for a while and then gives a blank screen). I'd say, that your curl-request might be trying to load a big amount of data, and that your PHP-configuration has a cap at 128mb (or something).

I'd check the PHPinfo for these two values:

```
max_input_vars
memory_limit
```

To see if either of them are suspiciously low.

Comment: This is more a series of comments than an answer.

Comment: @Nick ...and even not applicable since *"This only happens on my webserver, not on the local system"*.

Comment: I agree, Nick. But the question is too broad to come up with a single answer-suggestion, at the current stage. So I posted this, so that other that was in @RobrechtVM's situation, could follow the same steps as him, in order to figure out what the error is. Because even if someone else has the same error as him, - then it could be either of several things.

Comment: Thanks @Zeth I have updated my original answer to clearify few things